# Should a router be reset when it is under power or off power?

Tags: networking, router

A router usually has a hole, through which I can push a pin to reset the router.

Should a router be reset while it is connected to power or not?

Or it doesn't matter?

Thanks.

Comment: The router won't reset if it's not plugged in

Answer (score 2):

As @Ramhound mentioned, you can't reset your router if it's switched off.

To reset it, use the **30/30/30 rule.**

1. Hold the reset button for 30 seconds when the router is switched on.
2. Still holding the reset button, power off your router and hold the reset button for 30 more seconds.
3. Finally, switch your router back on, and continue holding the reset button for the last 30 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is to power on the router.
Then press the small button at the back of the router.
unplug the router from power source
re-connect the power and power on the router
connect the router to your system unit or laptop through direct cable
open a browser and type in the default IP e.g 192.168.0.1 
Note:the IP of your router can be found at back of the router.
finally you can change the settings to your taste
good-luck

Comment: Depending on the model of the router, the reset button might be a tiny button on the back of the router, but it is more common as a tiny hole to keep it from being pressed accidentally.